# Cognos equivalent of excel's sumif() function

Tags: cognos, sumifs, cognos-10, cognos-8

I'm familiar with Excel and SQL, but new to Cognos. I'm doing a conditional sum on `[Total Margin]` for each `[Item Code]`. This result should show on each row for the each item. I've tried 2 approaches in Cognos and a proof of concept in Excel. See below for sample data from a single `[Item Code]`.

[image: data screenshot]

**Total Item Margin A (Cognos)**

```
case
when [free of charge flag] = 'FALSE'
then total([Total Margin] for [Item Code])
else null
end
```

The problem here is that the TOTAL result is incorrect, and just fails to display on the 2nd row.

**Total Item Margin B (Cognos)**

```
total([Total Margin] for [Item Code],[free of charge flag])
```

Here the TOTAL result is correct on most rows, but different on the 2nd row.

**Total Item Margin C (Excel)**

```
=SUMIFS([Total Margin],[Item Code],'10001430',[free of charge flag],FALSE)
```

So I can get the result I want using an excel SUMIFS formula. What Cognos query do I need to write to get the same result directly from Cognos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try

```
total(
  case
  when [free of charge flag] = 'FALSE'
  then [Total Margin]
  else null
  end
for [Item Code])
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Working out the query syntax of a new system can be frustrating sometimes. Seems a nested CASE WHEN was required here.

Comment: The tool tips in Cognos 10 are next to useless sometimes when you can never see examples of how {expression} can really be utilized. This was a great example.